# Tableview category refinement

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a large amount of data in firebase that I am displaying on a tableview. The data is of different businesses nearby and I want to add a feature to filter/sort the data by business type(food, travel, shopping, ect..). I added a tab bar with a segmented control to work as the filter/sort feature. When the user selects shopping I want only the shopping business to display and all of the other business to delete. I have tried a few different ways to do this but not have worked successfully. I am able to populate the tableview cells correctly when the app first loads but I cannot correctly load the cells when a filter/sort option is selected. Here is my current code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var selects: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func selections(_ sender: Any) {
    if selects.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        //all
        print("all")
        cate = 0
        loadposts()
    }
    else if selects.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        //shopping
        print("shopping")
        cate = 1
        loadposts()
    }
    else if selects.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        //food
        print("food")
        cate = 2
        loadposts()
    }
    else if selects.selectedSegmentIndex == 3 {
        //travel
        print("travel")
        cate = 3
        loadposts()
    }
    else if selects.selectedSegmentIndex == 4 {
        //events
        print("event")
        cate = 4
        loadposts()
    }
    else {
        //more
        print("more")
        cate = 5
        loadposts()
    }
}

func loadposts() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let trace = Performance.startTrace(name: "test trace")
    trace?.incrementCounter(named:"retry")
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    print(userID!)


   ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let one1 = value?["Coupon Book"] as? String ?? ""
        let two2 = value?["charitylogo"] as? String ?? ""
        print("one1: \(one1)")
        bogus.set(one1, forKey: "bogus")
    let url = URL(string: two2)
    print("Url: \(url!)")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           /// self.centernavlogo = UIButton(type: .custom)
            let pim = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.vood.background = pim
            ///self.centernavlogo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
           /// self.centernavlogo.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
           /// self.centernavlogo.setImage(pim, for: .normal)
          ///  self.centernavlogo.setBackgroundImage(pim, for: .normal)

            /// self.centernavlogo.tintColor = UIColor.white

            ///self.centernavlogo.setBackgroundImage(pim, for: .normal)


        }

    }).resume()

    Database.database().reference().child("Coupons").child(one1).observe(.childAdded) { (Snapshot : DataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = Snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let captiontext = dict["company name"] as! String
            let offerx = dict["totaloffer"] as! String
            let logocomp = dict["logo"] as! String
            let actchild = dict["childx"] as! String
            let categ = dict["category"] as! String
            let post = Post(captiontext: captiontext, PhotUrlString: actchild, offertext: offerx, actualphoto: logocomp, cat2: categ)
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.tableview.reloadData()

            print(self.posts)
        }
    }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    trace?.stop()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

}
extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! prot

    if cate == 0{
        ///home
        if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "" {

        }else{

        }
    }else
    if cate == 1{
    ///shopping
    if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "shopping" {

    }
}else
    if cate == 2{
    ///food
    if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "food" {

    }
}else
    if cate == 3{
    ///travel
    if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "travel" {

    }
}else
    if cate == 4{
    ///event
    if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "event" {

    }
}else
    if cate == 5{
    ///more
    if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "more" {
            posts.remove(at: indexPath.item)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
        }
           print("category 5 running")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    if cate == 6{
        ///gps
    }

    cell.cllimg?.image = nil
    cell.maintxt.text = nil
    cell.sidetxt.text = nil
    cell.maintxt.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption
    cell.sidetxt.text = "Offers: \(posts[indexPath.row].offercount)"



    let hone = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let maria = hone.actphot {
        let url = URL(string: maria)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            cell.cllimg?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

            cell.cllimg?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }).resume()
    }

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    passinfo.set("\(posts[indexPath.row].photourl)", forKey: "passinfo")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegue", sender: self)
}



}
```

With the code above code, the table is blank when a category is selected

```
if cate == 5{
    ///more
    if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "more" {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
            posts.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
           print("category 5 running")
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

With the code above, the app crashes and gives me this error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (14) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (15), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I have also tried removing `posts.remove(at: indexPath.item)` and `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)` but neither worked.

Comment: Think about just using cate = selects.selectedSegmentIndex instead of the whole if else construct. I think the crash are exactly explaining what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line before `tableView.beginUpdates()`

```
posts.remove(at: indexPath.item)
```

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
>   (14) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
>   before the update (15), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or
>   deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus
>   the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0
>   moved out).

as the error suggest that the count of posts array before the update must be equal after the update too.

```
posts.remove(at: indexPath.item)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: It appears to work, but when I try to scroll down on the tableview the app crashes: "erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (17) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (19), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'"

Comment: that's because you are trying to `deleteRows` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Try adding `deleteRows` between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and remove the `tableView.reloadData`

Comment: Okay, I followed what you said but no I get this error 'fatal error: Index out of range
2017-10-05 21:47:26.188981-0400 mobile-4charityhelp[40778:2697908] fatal error: Index out of range' and this line of code was flagged 'if posts[indexPath.row].cat1 == "more" {'. What is happening is the cells are being deleted but when I scroll down to the bottom the cells reappear and then the app crashes.